# how to restrict duplicate value to insert in table before form.save()

Tags: django

I want to restrict duplicate entry of "business name" in my database. As I have created a form and function is taking value from the template and I am saving form data in DB and it is working fine but it is not checking duplicate entries before it inserting into Db. so what I want is code will check "business name" already present in DB or not. If data present with the code should give the message that data already present with this name else data will be saved.

### This is the model in the project

```
class SupplierModel(models.Model):
    mine_id = models.ForeignKey(MineDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    business_website=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='0000000000',blank=True,null=True)
    email= models.EmailField()
    pincode= models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    landmark= models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    area= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city= models.TextField(default='')
    state= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    map_loc= models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    pan= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    gstin= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    notes= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

function i wrote in views

```
@login_required
def supplier_add(request, template_name='SupplierDetails.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SupplierForm(request.POST)
        # print("abc")
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # return  HttpResponse("ok saved")
            return redirect('inventory_management:supplier_manage')
    else:
        form = SupplierForm()
        # print(form)
    # duplicates = SupplierModel.objects.values('business_name').annotate(name_count=Count('business_name')).filter(name_count__gt=1)
    # print(duplicates)
    # records = SupplierModel.objects.filter(business_name__in=[item['business_name'] for item in duplicates])
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/w3.css' %}">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Add Supplier Details
                <small>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspHere you can add/edit basic info of Item supplier</small>
                </h1>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'inventory_management:supplier_manage' %}">Manage Supplier</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- Table content -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border"><font color="blue">Mine Specific Details</font></legend>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label for="" class="" id="">Choose Mine:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    {{form.mine_id}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border"><font color="blue">Business Details</font></legend>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_business_name" class="" id="">Business Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.business_name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_business_website" class="" id="">Business Website</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.business_website}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border"><font color="blue">Contact Person</font></legend>
                             <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_name" class="" id="">Name<font color="red">*</font></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                       {{form.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="mobile_no" class="" id="">Mobile Number</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         {{form.mobile_no}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_email" class="" id="">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.email}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border"><font color="blue">Billing Address</font></legend>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="pin" class="" id="">Pincode</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.pincode}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="address" class="" id="">Address</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         {{form.address}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="landmark" class="" id="">Landmark</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.landmark}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_area" class="" id="">Area</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         {{form.area}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_city" class="" id="">City</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.city}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_state" class="" id="">State</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         {{form.state}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             <br/><br/> <br/><br/>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_map_location" class="" id="">Map Location</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.map_loc}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border"><font color="blue">Tax Details</font></legend>
                             <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_pan" class="" id="">PAN /TIN</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.pan}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_gstin" class="" id="">GSTIN</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.gstin}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="id_notes" class="" id="">Notes</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        {{form.notes}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!--end Table content -->
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<style>

    fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: solid 1px #DDD !important;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    width: auto !important;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
fieldset ul {list-style:none}

</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_mine_id").addClass('form-control');

});
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1900:2012",
      // You can put more options here.

    });
  });


</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is your SupplierForm is normal form or model form?

Answer (score 0):

Put this after form.is_valid(), before form.save():

```
if SupplierModel.objects.filter(business_name=form.cleaned_data['business_name'], ).exists():
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists

If uniqueness should not ignore NULLs then you can alter model field definition like this:

```
business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True, unique=True)
```

If multiple NULLs are allowed and only non-NULL values must be unique than this won't work.

Comment: No, this should be checked in the form. If the model field is unique the form will validate this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `unique=True` to the definition of `business_name` in the model.

Comment: Not provide error message if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SupplierForm(request.POST)
        # print("abc")
        if form.is_valid():
            if SupplierModel.objects.filter(business_name=form.cleaned_data['business_name'], ).exists():
               form.save()
               return  HttpResponse("Ya exist un business_name")
              # return  HttpResponse(" Duplicate entry")
            else:
               return redirect('inventory_management:supplier_manage')
    else:
       form = SupplierForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

Comment: I don't know what that comment means. Please update your question to post the full details with properly-formatted code.